# Interactive search results table

Tags: asp.net, database, vb.net, search

In Asp.net using Visual Basic code I want to be able to query a database after a user inputs search criteria, get the results and display them in a table, with the ability of the user to click/select individual results and delete the corresponding data from the database. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by utilizing a Datagridview and binding data to it (by using OLEDB for example). Use the WHERE clause in your query to filter the records, based on the user input. (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp)
The Datagrid has events you can use (delete, select, insert and update event).

See for more information: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBASPNETGridView-19039173

Good luck!